# php file_get_contents / header server difference

Tags: php, apache

I am accessing spreadsheets which are not located inside in the web directory and serving them to the browser. I am using the following code to do this:

```
$filePath = WEBSITE_ROOT_PATH.'/../where_the_spreadsheets_are/file_name.xls';

if(file_exists($filePath)){
    $contents = file_get_contents($filePath);                
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file_name.xls");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    echo $contents;
}
```

This code works correctly on 20+ separate servers, but not on one. On the one that fails Excel says that the spreadsheet is corrupt.

The server that fails has a mirror server, so the same file path and file name exists, and on this server the spreadsheet is ok.

It's a Win server 2007 running WAMP. All the rest are also Win Servers running WAMP.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Since file_get_contents renders the binary fileformat to a string, it could be a character encoding issue... But this is just guessing...

Comment: Open the _corrupt_ spreadsheet in a text editor and check the first few lines. May be there is a PHP error before the binary data.

Comment: You are setting multiple different `Content-Type` header, which all overwrite each other. The proper one is `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: There was no php error in the file and I removed the content type. I have also looked @ bom issues with the file creating it, whether it could be because it is outside of the web dir, ensured that the XLS is the same on both servers. It's a real head scratcher this one ...